# Send pyttsx3..save_to_file output to api

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I am trying to send pyttsx3.save_to_file to an api endpoint using python. e.g. i create a Flask api endpoint which receive some text from user -> convert text to speech -> and return the mp3 as byte array.

How this can be acheived?

Answer (score 0):

I could help better if you shared your code, but in general I do it like this:

```
import base64
import pyttsx3
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def index():
    text = request.data.decode('utf-8')
    file_name = "file.mp3"

    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.save_to_file(text, file_name)
    engine.runAndWait()

    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        mp3_bytes = f.read()

    mp3_file = base64.b64encode(mp3_bytes)
    return Response(mp3_file, mimetype='application/json')
```

Also you need to install libespeak1 and ffmpeg libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libespeak1
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

You can test it as follows:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" --data "Hello world" http://localhost:5000/ > file.mp3
```

Comment: hey, thanks sir, this looks like what I need. Let me try this today.